# how to update wp_usermeta table for a specific id

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to update some meta key from wp_usermeta table in wordpress.I have used this code but could not find my solution.Ihave tried this code.Any help will be highly appreciated

```
$newname=$_POST['name'];
    $parts = explode(" ", $newname);

    $newlname = array_pop($parts);
    $newfname = implode(" ", $parts);

    echo "Firstname: $newfname\n";
    echo "Lastname: $newlname\n";
    echo $id= $_POST['newid'];
echo $newaddress= $_POST['address'];
echo $newcity=$_POST['city'];
echo $newareacode=$_POST['acode'];


/* Start database connection */
       $dbhost = 'localhost';
       $dbuser = 'user';
       $dbpass = '';
       $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
       mysql_select_db('etplpm_network');
/* End  database connection */
 $sql="UPDATE wp_usermeta set 'first_name'=$newfname, 'last_name'=$newlname, 'billing_address_1'=$newaddress, 'billing_city'=$newcity, 'billing_postcode'=$newareacode WHERE 'ID'=$id"; 
     $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if($result)
{
    echo "Successfully Updated";

}
else
{
    echo "Successfully Not Updated";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your MySql syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta set 'first_name'=$newfname, 'last_name'=$newlname, 'billing_address_1'=$newaddress, 'billing_city'=$newcity, 'billing_postcode'=$newareacode WHERE 'ID'=$id;
```

You have to wrap by quotes field values, not field names:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET first_name = '$newfname', ...
```

But also this query will fail, because you have not checked `wp_usermeta` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_usermeta` (
  `umeta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So, you have first to check if a meta exists for specific user:

```
SELECT umeta_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id=$id AND meta_key='first_name'
```

Then, if the meta exists, update it:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='$newfname' WHERE umeta_id=...
```

Otherwise, insert new one:

```
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('$id', 'first_name', '$newfname')
```

But, why do not use worpress function `update_user_meta()` for that?

```
update_user_meta( $id, 'first_name',        '$newfname' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'last_name',         '$newlname' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_address_1', '$newaddress' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_city',      '$newcity' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_postcode',  '$newareacode' );
```

Comment: It gives error fatal error: call to undefined function update_user_meta. I am using                                                                            update_user_meta( $id, 'first_name',        '$newfname' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'last_name',         '$newlname' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_address_1', '$newaddress' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_city',      '$newcity' );
update_user_meta( $id, 'billing_postcode',  '$newareacode' );

Comment: If you want to use WP functions, you have to write the code in a wp theme page or in a plugin. Otherwise you have to use MySQL syntax provided in my answer.